# Removing LOB column from table. Lob used page count not equals to 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I altered a table that was used to contains a Lob column (VarBinary(MAX)).

When I run

```
select * from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where [object_id] = object_id('MyTable')
```

the lob_used_page_count is 1014969. I thought it would be 0. Am I wrong or is there something I need to do?

Comment: Can you explain the difference ? I think it has a clustered index (because of PK) but I am not sure of the meaning of heap

Comment: The table is just containing a couple of int, a Guid and a couple of NVarChar(64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ALTER TABLE MyTable REBUILD`.

Seems to do the trick from the test below.

```
CREATE TABLE LobTest
  (
     PK INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     A  CHAR(7000),
     B  VARCHAR(MAX)
  )

INSERT INTO LobTest
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 10000) UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 10000) UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 10000)

ALTER TABLE LobTest
  DROP COLUMN B

SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE  [object_id] = object_id('LobTest')

ALTER TABLE LobTest REBUILD

SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE  [object_id] = object_id('LobTest')

DROP TABLE LobTest
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The demo script? I changed it from using `VALUES` to `UNION ALL` so does it work now?

Comment: @PitMing - On 2005 I think you need `ALTER INDEX YourPKName ON MyTable REBUILD`

Comment: Sorry @MartinSmith, didn't see this comment before I posted my answer

Comment: @MartinSmith the command "Alter table MyTable Rebuild" is only available since SQL Server 2008. Not in 2005.

Comment: @PitMing - Yes I saw that in BOL. Hence suggestion above to use `ALTER INDEX YourPKName ON MyTable REBUILD` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the Clustered Index. When you drop a column in SQL Server, it is not actually physically deleted until the clustered index is rebuilt.